# Instantiating Objects from Inside the Static Method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. For some reason when I try to instantiate the Movie objects from inside the getAllMovies static method I get the error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Movie.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at new Movie (Movie.js:7)

import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Movie extends Component {

  constructor(name, year, genre) {
    this.name = name
    this.year = year
    this.genre = genre
  }

  static getAllMovies() {

    let movies = []
    let movie = new Movie("ss","sss","aaa")

    /*
    for(let index = 1; index <= 10; index++) {

      let movie = new Movie(`Movie {index}`,2000 + index,`Genre {index}`)
      movies.push(movie)

    } */

    return movies

  }

}
```

Comment: Darn! I missed that. Thanks Mark. If you can post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Movie` class needs to call `super()` in it's constructor to have the correct value for `this`:

```js
class Component{}

class Movie extends Component {

  constructor(name, year, genre) {
    super()
    this.name = name
    this.year = year
    this.genre = genre
  }

  static getAllMovies() {
    let movie = new Movie("ss","sss","aaa")
    return movie
  }

}

console.log(Movie.getAllMovies())
```

Comment: Agreed @Bergi, I assumed it was coming from something down the line in the build. Maybe this answer is too incomplete given that it's a react component subclass.

Comment: I have noticed that ReactJS and React Native both are really bad at providing correct/context sensitive error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think your concept about react was wrong.
In react component, `props` and `state` are used for data management.
So the statement are below:

```
class Movie extends component{
     constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = {
               name : this.props.name,
               year : this.props.year,
               genre : this.props.genre,
          }
     }
```

the above error was occurred because of your constructor